# How to visualize frequency of a survey answer with circles/bubbles of different sizes in R

Tags: r, visualization, frequency

What is this type of data visualization plot called and how do I recreate it in R?

[image: Visualization of Answer Frequency in differently sized Bubbles/Circles]

Image Source: https://www.pewresearch.org/global/2020/04/30/worldwide-optimism-about-future-of-gender-equality-even-as-many-see-advantages-for-men/pg_2020-04-30_global-gender-equality_0-02/

My Google search only resulted in regular bubble plots like this: https://r-graph-gallery.com/320-the-basis-of-bubble-plot.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```r
df <- data.frame(Question = rep(c("Getting\nhigh-paying jobs", 
                                  "Being leaders in\ntheir community",
                                  "Expressing their\npolitical views", 
                                  "Getting a good\neducation"), 3),
                 Answer = rep(c("Men have more\nopportunities",
                                "Women have more\nopportunities",
                                "Both about\nthe same"), each = 4),
                 Value = c(54, 44, 31, 11, 3, 4, 3, 6, 38, 49, 63, 81))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(y    = factor(Question, rev(unique(Question))),
               x    = factor(Answer, unique(Answer)),
               fill = factor(Answer, unique(Answer)))) +
  geom_point(shape = 21, aes(size = Value, color = after_scale(fill))) +
  geom_text(aes(label = Value, color = Answer)) +
  annotate("segment", x = rep(-Inf, 3), xend = rep(Inf, 3),
           y = 1:3 + 0.5, yend = 1:3 + 0.5, linetype = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  scale_y_discrete() +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(5, 30)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#959e4a", "#0f6599", "#dddac8")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "white", "white")) +
  ggtitle(paste("Many think men have more opportunities than women",
                "when it comes to getting high-paid jobs", sep = "\n")) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        axis.text.x = element_text(face = 2),
        axis.text.y = element_text(hjust = 1, face = 2),
        plot.margin = margin(30, 30, 30, 30),
        plot.title = element_text(size = 16, face = 2, family = "serif",
                                  margin = margin(20, 0, 50, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: lol, yeah I bet the original poster is looking for something like that. But clearly the fonts and line dot sizes need to be updated before this can go to publication. ;-)

Comment: most nifty use of `annotate`!

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for and more! Do you know if there is a specific name for this kind of visualization? Bubble Plot?

Comment: I guess it is _kind of_ a bubble plot with two categorical axes. More like a table with bubble annotations - I don't think I have seen this given a name specifically @marina, though it is quite a nice visualization.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example. Lots more formatting tweaks could be done, but I'd think of this fundamentally as a `geom_point` and a `geom_text` layer, the rest is tidying up.

```
library(ggplot2)
fake_data <- data.frame(x = rep(LETTERS[1:3], each = 4),
                        y = letters[1:4],
                        val = (1:12) / 12)

    
ggplot(fake_data, aes(x=1, y = 1, label = scales::percent(val))) +
  geom_point(aes(size = val, color = x), alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_text() + 
  scale_size_area(max_size = 20) +
  guides(size = "none", color = "none") +
  facet_grid(y ~ x, switch = "y") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(strip.text = element_text())
```

[image]